# Make Sequelize seed after fields in other columns

Tags: migration, sequelize.js, database-migration, sequelize-cli

Is there any way in Sequelize to add another column and then populate it with the contents of another column(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using migrations.

Something like

```
queryInterface.addColumn(
  'MyAwesomeTable',
  'myAwesomeColumn',
  {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    default: 6
  }
).then(() => {

   return queryInterface.sequelize.query('UPDATE MyAwesomeTable SET myAwesomeColumn = someOtherColumn')
})
```